# GCM Service. Push Notification

Tags: android

Если приложение закрыто (не запущено), то нужно запускать одну активити во время клика по нотификации. А если приложение запущено, то другую Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Причем тут GCM? Это относится к флагам [PendingIntent.getActivity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html), которые задаются в нотификации. В зависимости от этого можно запускать или наоборот не запускать новую `Activity` при нажатии на нотификацию.

Answer (score 1):

1) Переопределите класс Application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    public static final boolean IS_ACT_RUNNING = false;
}
```

2) Укажите в манифесте этот класс в специальном теге.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ... >

    ...
    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeDark" >
    ...

        <receiver
            android:name=".NotifClickBroadcastReceiver "
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="myAction" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3) В этом классе заведите переменную `IS_ACT_RUNNING` типа `boolean`

4) В нужной активити в методах onResume() присваивайте переменной true; в onPause() - false;

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.IS_ACT_RUNNING=true;
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    MyApplication.IS_ACT_RUNNING=false;
}
```

5) При клике на уведомление проверяйте эту переменную. Так вы будете знать запущенна ли искомая активити.

```
public class NotifClickBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        String isActRunning = String.valueOf(        MyApplication.IS_ACT_RUNNING);
        Log.e("LOG", "isActRunning: "+isActRunning );
    }
}
```

При создании уведомления указывайте вызов вышеозначенного ресивера по клику на уведомление:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, NotifClickBroadcastReceiver.class);
    i.setAction("myAction");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(pi);
```

Comment: Вы хоть стандартные примеры кода, что-ли, написали бы. Новичкам, типа меня, не понятно будет, как использовать Ваш пример

Comment: @zayn1991, да не вопрос.

Comment: Примеров сбросил, так сбросил =D

Answer (score 0):

Завести где-то флаг, определяющий, запущено приложение, или нет.